# Implement ad banner in Fragment android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, admob

I have managed to implement the anchored adaptive banner as explained in this tutorial ([anchored adaptive banner](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/banner/anchored-adaptive)).
First within an Activity and then within a Fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    context ?: return binding.root
    setupAdview(binding)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    return binding.root
}
```

Then I have the following in my fragment class:

```
override fun onPause() {
    adView.pause()
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    adView.resume()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    adView.destroy()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

I am using single activity with navigation component. When I start the app, the ads are showing great. When I then move to another fragment and return back, the ads aren't showing anymore.

Comment: If the Fragment is destroyed during navigation, it will destroy the `AdView` as well. If you are only using the `AdView` at a fixed location then you can use it in the Activity.

Comment: Hi @DarShan. Only that fragment has the ads banner underneath a collapsing toolbar, the other fragment have a simple toolbar with no ads banner. This is the reason I haven't put the ads banner in the Activity

Comment: How about creating the `AdView` instance in the `Activity` & reference it from that specific Fragment only via `(activity as MainActivity).adView`? You can simply use `adView.pause()` if that Fragment is not in view i.e. while navigation.

Comment: I was using `findNavController().navigateUp()` to navigate back to the main fragment. Changing it to `findNavController().navigate(directions)` where directions is defined in xml with `app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` works great.